# Scheme program as a list of symbols

Tags: scheme, guile

I have to pass entire scheme program as a list to my user-defined function/predicate "is-s-list?" which identifies if the scheme program passed as a list is a list of symbols or not.

However, I am not understanding how can I take scheme program as a list...?

I tried this:

```
(define P '())  ....i.e a null list
(append P "my entire program")
```

Now, i face some problems here while doing car/cdr in function "is-s-list?"

How should I analyze the components of program to identify if a program is a list of symbols? And, is a program really a list of just the scheme symbols? So should I return #f after checks using (symbol? (car P)) are over?

What I am trying to do is this :

In languages like scheme, we represent code, i.e expressions as lists of symbols.

Write a predicate, "is-s-list?" that takes another program as a list and returns true if it is a symbolic list.

Comment: everything in scheme is a list. what do you mean by "list of symbols"?

Comment: Let's be precise. 13 is not a list. "abc" is not a list.

Comment: I think we need more context. I'm guessing that you're taking a programming languages class, and that your instructor is choosing to use the powers of "quote" to turn parenthesized strings into lists. I'm further guessing that you're being asked to write a function that determines whether an arbitrary value is a list of strings. Is all that correct?

Comment: If you quote your program using`'`, it will not excute unless you call `eval` on it, but considered as some list data not quite differ from '(a b (d e)).

Comment: In MIT-scheme: If you define an expression a like (define a '( .....)), then a will be a proper list if the interpreter will accept the "define"-expression. Except from numbers, strings and #f, #t and '() any thing what is not pair will be symbol. Now: Can you give an examples for which  "is-s-list?" will return '#f' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Scheme program as **one expression**

```
(begin
  (define a 10)
  (define b 13)
  (define (square n)
    (* n n))
  (+ (square a) (square b)))
; ==> 269
```

Here is the same program as data, bound to the variable `code`:

```
(define code 
  '(begin
     (define a 10)
     (define b 13)
     (define (square n)
       (* n n))
     (+ (square a) (square b))))

code ; ==> (begin ....) (a list of symbols and the occational number)
```

The main difference is the `'` which changes the expression that follows to be interpreted as data instead of code. In many other programming languages `eval` takes a string since they don't have data types defined to represent code as data. This is mostly a LISP feature.

Comment: Thanks....this is what I was somewhat looking for.... But I need some more help... Now I am taking this variable "code" as input to my function "is-symbolic-list?", like this: "is-symbolic-list? code"  .... in the function, when I do (car code) i get the first symbol which is "begin" ....and then I pass (cdr code) to function again to reassign (cdr code) to code in a recursive call.... This time when i do (car code) , it gives me "define a 10" and it comes out to print #f as it is not a symbol.... Is this correct?

Comment: @HarshadaKelkar A Scheme program can be just one expression consisting of a list with just symbols, but most often you have subexpressions like in my example where `(define ...)` is a list in the program list. If this is allowed then `is-symbolic-list?` needs to support that a list can consist of symbols or lists where `is-symbolic-list?` is true. `eval` does eomething similar. `(+ 1 2)` is ok, but so is `(* (+ 1 2) (+ 1 2))` since you have the symbol `+` and two "programs" as arguments. Now "programs" are just Scheme **expressions**.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp expression is tree kind of structure 
so you have to parse some kind of binary tree 
following link might help you

[S-expr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)